Why does the .filterBounds function not work for FIRMS data in GEE?
I am currently trying to filter all wildfires in a certain area from FIRMS data.
Link to GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/26d53b5b6745fbddae1bfa27392d7eb5
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
    .filterDate('2018-08-01', '2018-08-10')
    .filterBounds(geometry);
var fires = dataset.select('T21');
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0,
  palette: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
};
Map.setCenter(-119.086, 47.295, 6);
Map.addLayer(fires, firesVis, 'Fires');

For the geometry
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-125.52398828125, 49.342659280871665],
          [-125.52398828125, 45.26289882018728],
          [-114.97711328125, 45.26289882018728],
          [-114.97711328125, 49.342659280871665]]], null, false);

However, Google Earth Engine just ignores this and proceeds to give FIRMS data for all fires in that date range all over the world. If not using the FilterBounds function, how else should I filter

You need to cycle over each image in the ImageCollection and clip it individually with .clip(geometry):
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
    .filterDate('2018-08-01', '2018-08-10');
    
dataset = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.clip(geometry);
});

var fires = dataset.select('T21');
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0,
  palette: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
};
Map.setCenter(-119.086, 47.295, 6);
Map.addLayer(fires, firesVis, 'Fires');

